# django tutorial problem: no module named pysqlite2

Tags: django, sqlite

Im following the django tutorial from http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

but I have a problem at step:python manage.py sql polls

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfiguraed:Error loading pysqlite2 module: No module named pysqlite2

My system is windows vista,and python version 2.5  django version 1.1

only thing I changed in setting.py is
 DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3'           # 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
 DATABASE_NAME = 'L:/django/mysite/mysite.db'

and add 'mysite.polls' in INSTALLED_APPS = ()

Comment: Im sorry. I found the reason why, 
I did all these steps in my netbook. it works well
and then I go back to my pc,
its a HP pc,and HP did load python 2.4 in C:/hp/python which i didnt notice that(I dont know why HP need python), after I remove c:/hp/python  it works fine now

Answer (score 4):

From browsing around it looks like early revisions of Python 2.5 may not have pysqlite2 installed for Django to take advantage of.

Therefore, you can either [download and install pysqlite](http://oss.itsystementwicklung.de/trac/pysqlite/) or you can upgrade your [python](http://www.python.org/) installation. 2.6 works quite nicely.

Hope that helps!